# Swift Find Last Scheduled Local Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

Do to the 64 local notification limit I am trying to find the notification that is furthest away from the current date. Currently my code is:

```
if let scheduledLocalNotifications = UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications {
    if let farthestLocalNotification = scheduledLocalNotifications.maxElement({ (notification1, notification2) -> Bool in
        guard let fireDateNotification1 = notification1.fireDate, fireDateNotification2 = notification2.fireDate else { return false }
        return fireDateNotification1.isBefore(fireDateNotification2)
    }) {
            return farthestLocalNotification
       }
    }
    return nil
}
```

This works fine but when profiling it, it is fairly slow. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: What makes it slow?

Comment: The time profiler just pinpoints maxElement

Comment: And so how long is it taking? What is "fairly slow"?

Comment: Averaging around 100 ms

Comment: Why not do it on a background thread? Then the elapsed time won't matter.

Comment: Currently I am doing on a background thread, but sometimes it doesn't finish before the user leaves the application. So I am looking for ways to speed it up so this is less likely to happen. After profiling this is the biggest time bottleneck

Comment: "but sometimes it doesn't finish before the user leaves the application" Did you know that there is a way to ensure that it does finish even if the user leaves the application? That way, you can do any required cleanup in the background before the app is suspended.

Comment: That'd be great. How would I go about doing that? I thought the OS cut off your processes after a few seconds

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1623031-beginbackgroundtask - example of usage here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch25p868mandelbrotGCD/ch38p1106mandelbrotNoThreading/MyMandelbrotView.swift

Comment: Helpful thanks. This doesn't seem to be executing if the app gets swiped out of the background, is this correct?